# Remove links from Custom Bing Search result page

Tags: asp.net, .net, bing, bing-api, bing-custom-search

We're using custom Bing search ( https://www.customsearch.ai/ ) as a custom search solution in our website. Initially we were having some pdfs and those are now removed from the server but when we search those pdfs, related links are still showing on search result page. When we click those links, we're getting 404 page which is expected because now those pdfs doesn't exist.

I guess somehow links are indexed and remains somewhere in custom Bing search.

Is there any process to clear orphan links from search result page? Is there any configuration that we can set up so that going forward if we remove pdfs from the server, related links are also removed?

Comment: Did you try and Google it?

Comment: @VDWWD Yes. 1st options is to remove pdf from site and return 404 page so we're doing that already. 2nd options is to use noindex meta tag but we can't use that meta tag on search result page because search result page show all other pdf links which are still valid. Is there any other option that we can try?

Comment: After further research, I tried both options( Remove Page and Remove outdated cache ) in Bing Content Removal Tool but in both options I'm getting below error during submission: `We could not verify that the URL is no longer live on the web or outdated. Please check the URL for errors or try again later. Your request will not be submitted.`